# What does the minus sign in a Bell state imply?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-teleportation

I know that the Bell states $|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle \pm |01\rangle)$ and $|\Phi^{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|11\rangle \pm |00\rangle)$ represent correlated ($|\Phi^{\pm}\rangle$) and anti-correlated ($|\Psi^{\pm}\rangle$) pairs of particles. I understand that each state vector represents a state with two possible measurement outcomes of equal probability.

What is the physical significance of the second term being positive or negative? For example,

$ |\Psi^{-}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle - |01\rangle)$,

$ |\Psi^{+}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|10\rangle + |01\rangle)$.

Measurements on $|\Psi^{-}\rangle$ and $|\Psi^{+}\rangle$ both have a 50% chance of resulting in $|10\rangle$ and a 50% chance of resulting in $|01\rangle$. But they are not the same state, due to the minus sign in $|\Psi^{-}\rangle$. What is the physical significance of the minus sign? How are $|\Psi^{-}\rangle$ and $|\Psi^{+}\rangle$ experimentally distinguishable?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the setting you're considering and provide the formula the question's about?

Comment: Sure, I'm talking about the bell states regarding quantum teleportation, when someone applies a Bell state measurement onto a qubit and an entangled particle it is projected on one of the following states:https://puu.sh/yLfGX/5cb89139a5.png I know the difference between the phi and psi states but I can't understand the difference between minus and plus sign.

Comment: Plus or minus could be as simple as up and down or left and right. If Stern-Gerlach devices are used to measure entangled electrons the particles will register up or down (+ -). If the devices are rotated horizontally they will register left and right (+ -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you mean are the different [Bell states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state) conventionally written as
$$\lvert\Phi^\pm\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\lvert00\rangle\pm\lvert11\rangle),$$
then the minus sign just represents a phase difference between the $\lvert00\rangle$ and $\lvert11\rangle$ states.
There can be two different quantum states corresponding to the same probabilities of observing $\lvert00\rangle$ and $\lvert11\rangle$.
These states are orthogonal, which implies that they are "easily" distinguishable, and act differently under unitary evolutions.

Also, it's worth noting that the use of $\lvert\Phi^\pm\rangle$ is really just conventional. You could have equivalently used another pair of orthogonal states like
$$\lvert\Xi_\phi^\pm\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(\lvert00\rangle\pm e^{i\phi}\lvert11\rangle),$$
without much changing.